# From where .htaccess called?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp

Using WAMP. When we run any of PHP application. First it calls `htaccess`.

I think Apache call it first when u specify in any of the folder.

Comment: If all else fails you could always try [looking in the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 2):

The standard configuration of WAMP Apache is that it looks in every folder from the `DocumentRoot` downwards to the folder the is being served. Higher folders are processed first. However, this can all be configured in your Apache configuration file.

A quick Google on "Apache .htaccess" will reveal much!

As a starting point, try looking in the '[WAMP install folder]/apache/apache.x.x.x/conf/httpd.conf' file for the directive 'AllowOverrides'.

Answer (score 1):

in virtual host you can disable htaccess with **AllowOverride None**

[Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)